# Deleting some elements in a vector based on their indices matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector which has around 250000 element `data` and I am trying to remove some indices. I managed to remove the beginning and the ending indices by applying `data = data(3001:203000)` .
but now I need to divide the vector to 40 by 5000 element and delete all the odd 5000's so the first 5000 will be removed from the array and 3rd .. 5th and so on. I need to have only the even 5000s in the vector. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is the `reshape` function.

Assuming our `data` is just a collection of indices from `1:250000` you can use the following:

```
data = 1:250000;
data = (3001:203000);
data = reshape(data,5000,40)'; %reshape data to be 5000 x 40, then transpose for the desired order
```

`data` is now `40 x 5000` and looks like...

```
3001, 3002, 3003, ... , 7999, 8000
8001, 8002, 8003, ... , 12999, 13000
.
.
.
198001, 198002, ..., 202999, 203000
```

After which you can select only the even numbered rows by indexing them like so:

```
data = data(2:2:40,:);
```

And finally reshape back into a single row as desired.

```
data = reshape(data',100000,1);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need delete the first 5000 (from 3001 till 8000) and then use the second 5000 (from 8001 till 13000) and delete the third and keep the fourth and so on .. and I need  the values to be in one vector not a matrix

Comment: You can reshape back into the vector you need. The call to `data = data(2:2:40)` should have deleted 3001 to 8000 and the following odd rows unless I'm not understanding exactly what you're looking for. There might be a better way of doing this without using reshape twice, but it's not apparent at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

could make a program that takes your vector and then creates the desired vector like:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6 ] %your vector
for i = 1:2:length(A) % increases by 2, so it skips every other index
    B = A(i);
end

disp(B)

B = [1,3,5]
```

Its a little unclear what you mean by odd 5000's and even 5000's